# Retrieving certificate data programmatically from a Configuration Profile in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ssl

I have been searching all over the apple documentation, including these forums, yet was not able to retrieve a certificate from a configuration profile that I had created and installed on my iPhone.

More specifically: Using the iPhone Configuration Utility, I created a simple configuration profile that contains a certificate under the Credentials tab.

I am now trying to retrieve this certificate using my iPhone app but without any luck of coming across useful documentation/examples.

I know how to extract PKCS12 data - I just don't know where to find the certificate data to begin with. Is there a path to the certificate data or to an NSDictionary of configuration profile values?